# I backed up a git project, and got "fatal: Not a Git Repository"

Tags: git

I backed up a git folder from Linux onto a FAT32 external drive, and copied it back later, and it said

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

What may have gone wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add to your answer, there was a [proposition of a patch back in 2007](http://lists.zerezo.com/git/msg632490.html) allowing for name like '`head`' instead of only '`HEAD`'.

Needless to say, this proposition was not exactly welcomed:

> > Now, I realise that this might open a can of worms ... would we also want to go looking for files called "`pack-ab~1.pac`" ?
>
> Hell, no.

So, to this day people still rename head in HEAD when [that happens](http://fourth-hand.blogspot.com/2009/01/fat-filesystems-and-git.html).

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to ask git to say that it can't find a file called "HEAD"?

Comment: Possible? Yes. But they will expect also some patch (code) to be proposed along with this request. And so far, no actual solution has been proposed...

Answer (score 3):

[How to break your git repository](http://glokal.eu/content/how-break-your-git-repository) suggests trying either

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod a-x
```

or renaming `head` to `HEAD`.

The latter fixed it for me.