# Cloning a repository without making it the origin remote

Tags: git, git-clone

I'm cloning a git repository from a computer that's going to be wiped.

Is it possible to clone a repository without making the original repository `origin/master`? Or do I need to clone it, and then delete the remote branch (which is done with `git remote rm origin`)?

**Edit**: The repository has only one branch, and no tags.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It is not necessary to make the original repository the "origin" remote to clone the master branch.

On the new machine, create a new repository:

```
git init foo
```

Then pull the old repository into the new one, without creating a remote:

```
cd foo
git pull <reference to old repository>
```

However, it should be noted that the easiest way to save off a repository would be to just zip the repository's directory up and move the files to a new machine.  That will preserve any and all remotes, tags, etc.

As noted below, when copying the repository, be careful when going from case-sensitive file systems (eg. Linux, Mac, NTFS) to non-case sensitive (eg. Fat32).

Comment: That's cool, I didn't know you could do that. Can you clone non-master branches that way as well?

Comment: If applying the latter, don't copy something from a non-FAT32 to a FAT32 partition and back again. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754108/i-backed-up-a-git-project-and-got-fatal-not-a-git-repository

Comment: Would you do the former with or without `file:///`, ie using `git pull /home/username/blah` versus `git pull file:///home/username/blah`?

Comment: If it's a local repository, you can just use /home/username/blah

Comment: And yes, ebneter, you can clone non-branches that way as well.  Like this:  git pull <ref to repo> <name of branch>. eg:

    git pull /home/jess/bar-repository my_alternate_branch

Comment: I had no tags after `git init` and `git pull <repo-ref>`, can get those afterwards with `git fetch --tags <repo-ref>`. No remote will be added.

Answer (score 9):

First, you can use `--origin <name>` option of [`git clone`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git-core/docs/git-clone.html)

> *--origin <name>*, *-o <name>*
>
> > Instead of using the remote name **origin** to keep track of the upstream repository, use **<name>**.

Second, you can use [`git remote add`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git-core/docs/git-remote.html) to add repository to fetch from to existing repository (so you can use `git init`, then `git remote add <name> <url>`).

---

If you want to create a mirror of repository, with `refs/heads/*` going into `refs/heads/*` in clone, you can `init` repository, setup appropriate refspec, and then `fetch`...

Or you can use **`git clone --mirror`**, which should answer current version of OP question.

This would however not preserve configuration (including remotes), worktree state, reflogs, etc.  For this you would need to copy repository whole, as [Jess Bowers said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2249681/46058).

Comment: The problem with using `--origin` is that ***you have to specify an origin remote***, correct? I'm trying to find a simple way to clone (or effectively clone) such that the clone doesn't have any remote aliases configured. Of course you could always do `git remote rm origin`, but I was hoping to find something that would do this in one step instead.

Comment: @Cupcake: Unfortunately there is (as far as I know) no one-step solution.  You can either clone (1) then remove 'origin' remote information (2), or initialize repository (1) and fetch all branches and tags using URL rather than remote name (2).

Comment: Your answer is for a different question than the one asked.

Comment: @JasonS: Either I have misread the original question, or (what is more probable), it was changed and clarified in the meantime.

Comment: History of the OP shows the original meaning of the question didn't change

Answer (score 4):

The general way to handle such a transfer would be **[`git bundle`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bundle.html)**.  See [Backup of github repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251713/backup-of-github-repo/1251717#1251717).

From your second (new) desktop:

```
git bundle create file:///\\oldDesktop/share/myGitRepo --all
```

to create one local file from which you will be able to clone a local git repo.

**Note:** the `file:///` protocol will support UNC (Universal Naming Convention) Windows path, with the rest of the path using '`/`' instead of '`\`'.  See [Git on a Windows Lan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230500/git-on-a-windows-lan/2230655#2230655).

Answer (score 2):

I do believe you would need to delete the remote branch.

Comment: If you want it name something else, you could do git clone -o not_origin

Comment: The problem is that when you delete the remote (not remote branch), you delete all the remote/<remote-name> branches as well.

Comment: @ebneter: what do you mean by "delete the remote (not remote branch)"?

Comment: @Andrew Grimm: The "remote" is what's configured by 'git remote'; I think of the "remote branch" as being the corresponding branch on the remote repo. That is, something you'd delete with 'git push origin :branch', which actually removes the branch on the remote.

git's terminology is a little confusing in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

Does the remote repo have more branches than just master? It's trickier if it does; you need to make local copies of all of the branches as well because when you delete the remote, all the remote/origin branches will go away. (I just tried it!)

So, you can do something like this:

```
git clone <remote_url>
cd <repo>
for b in $(git branch -r | grep -v HEAD | grep -v master);do
    git branch $(basename $b) $b
done
git remote rm origin
```

Of course, as Jess Bowers said, it's even easier to just tar or zip it up and move the files, if you have access to the machine to do that.

You can also just make a bare clone:

```
git clone --bare <remote_url>
```

and then make new clones from that.