# Git repository broken after moving files and directories

Tags: git

I moved a bunch of files and directories around (including my .git directory) then back, and now git is broken

this is the error message I get:

`fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

apparently the solution is to rename `head` to `HEAD`, according to [I backed up a git project, and got "fatal: Not a Git Repository"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754108/i-backed-up-a-git-project-and-got-fatal-not-a-git-repository)

My problem is now that I only have `ORIG_HEAD` and not `head`.  Can I just rename `ORIG_HEAD` to `HEAD` and git my git repo back? (sorry for the pun, I had to)

Comment: I probably should not have asked this question and just tried it myself first, but oh well, now it's here and may be useful for someone else.

I copied ORIG_HEAD to HEAD and my git repo did indeed start working again (though the HEAD is now at a commit much older than it used to be before I screwed up my repo).

Comment: So, if this is a question in the form of an answer, then should we answer in the form of a question? "I'll take Science for $200, Alex." =P Thanks for the tip, and good luck with the recovery.

Comment: it is customary to post a self-answer as an answer. You can even accept it (I think after some delay (hours?))

Comment: @sehe It told me that I could after 7 or 8 hrs, but I didn't think I could remember to come back to it then :)

Comment: [meta] you can easily go into [your profile page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/635032/bodhi) and scan through the list of questions. 'accept'ed answers show up as _yellow on green_ (a.o.p white on green)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try git reflog to see whether it still knows your proper 'last' head, chances are it has it:

```
 git log HEAD@{0}
```

or

```
 git log HEAD@{1}
```

If you want to go back there,

```
 git checkout -b rescue HEAD@{0} # or whatever head it was
```

To create a rescue branch. If you're sure enough it is the right version (*and you don't have any uncommit changes you wanted to keep*):

```
 git reset --hard HEAD@{0} # or whatever head it was
```

Comment: ahh, nice!  Hadn't known what reflog did until now - very useful!  I believe I used a `git reset --hard my_SHA` to put the HEAD pointer back to where I wanted it, and all was well.  `reflog` could also have been very helpful if I had a more complex situation

Comment: this [gitready link](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/09/reflog-your-safety-net.html) was great for explaining reflog to me, btw